# Why collection reducer is necessary in this @ngrx effects example?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

There are four reducers used in the [@ngrx effects](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/b2aa4fe70400da223d8fe092befc38b9326945e3/src/app/reducers) example namely (1) books (2) collection (3) layout and (4) search. I don't understand why a `collection` reducer is necessary here because the `books` reducer already reflects the state of the collection after an `add` or `remove` operation. I see the use of the `collection` reducer as to track the `loading` and `loaded` status only.

Look at the final state of the books being create with `getBookCollection`. The `getBookEntities` reflect the state of the collection after any add or remove, so does not have to compose with the `collection` reducer.

Am I missing any logic here?

```
export const getCollectionState = (state: State) => state.collection;

export const getCollectionLoaded = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getLoaded);
export const getCollectionLoading = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getLoading);
export const getCollectionBookIds = createSelector(getCollectionState, fromCollection.getIds);

export const getBookCollection = createSelector(getBookEntities, getCollectionBookIds, (entities, ids) => {
  return ids.map(id => entities[id]);
});
```

Comment: how would you otherwise get collection from server without adding/removing items? just pure get.

Comment: The collection represents the items that are available on the client side.

Comment: of course but you seem to assume that those items could come into client side state only through add/remove actions. my point is they could also be loaded into state by simply getting them from server.

Answer (score 0):

The books state doesn't reflect the collection state after an add or removal of a book from the user's book collection.

Using the redux devtools this first image shows that I have 2 books in my books state and 2 books in my collection state:

[image: Two books in collection]

After removing one of the books you can see that the books state stays the same and the collection now only has one id.

[image: One book in collection]